# Why does it seem like that a tangent line of an odd-degree polynomial function crosses the curve at more than one point?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, tangent-line

This question has bothered me for a long time. I know that a tangent line only crosses a curve at one specific point. However, consider this:

Let $f(x)=x^3$
The derivative of this function is $f^\prime(x)=3x^2$
Suppose that I want to know the equation of the tangent line at $x=1$. To determine the slope, I just need to plug $x=1$ into $f^\prime(x)$ :
$f^\prime(1)=3(1)^2=3$

Therefore, the slope at $x=1$ of $f(x)$ is $3$.
Using the slope formula, I get $(y-1)=3(x-1)$
Solving for $y$, I get $y=3x-2$

Therefore, the tangent line equation of the cubic curve at $x=1$ is
$y=3x-2$

I would think that the tangent line will only intersects the cubic curve at a single point, but when I typed this into the Desmos Calculator , it intersects on the curve at two points $(1,1)$ and $(-2,-8)$.

This is actually different for a quadratic function. Consider this:

Let $f(x)=x^2$
Then $f^\prime(x)=2x$

Suppose that I want to find the slope of the function at $x=1$:
$f^\prime(1)=2(1)=2$
The equation of the tangent line at the point when $x=1$ is
$(y-1)=2(x-1)$
$y=2x-1$

When I typed this into the Desmos Calculator , it shows me that the only solution to this pair of system of equation is $(1,1)$

Why did this happen? Am I misunderstanding something? Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you allow complex intersection points, any tangent line of $y=x^n$ intersects the curve at $n$, not necessarily distinct, points given by an equation of the form $mx+c=x^n.$ For example, consider the tangent line to $y=x^3$ at $(0, 0).$

Comment: @Bumblebee, what do you mean by "complex intersection points"? I am blind, so if you can explain this in terms of words, that will be greatly apreciated. Of course, I can picture in my head the shape of a cubic curve.

Comment: For another example, the tangent line to $y=x^5$ at $(1, 1)$ is $y=5x-4.$ Now, if you solve the equation $5x-4=x^5$, you can see exactly three real solutions ($x=1$ twice) and two complex conjugates.

Comment: @Bumblebee, It is possible that the asker (working over real numbers) has not heard of complex numbers, and if that is the case, your comments are not comprehensible to the asker. On the other hand, once someone is familiar with complex numbers, you are right they can be helpful to understand the most general cases.

Comment: Oh...that makes a lot of sense:) - I thought that "complex intersection" is another type of visual concepts. It turned out to be the solutions to a function where the solutions are imaginary.

Comment: The tangent of $\cos x$ at $x=0$ touches the curve at infinite points $2n\pi$ for every integer $n$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your misunderstanding is that "a tangent line only crosses a curve at one specific point".  If a line $L$ is tangent to a curve $C$ at a point $P$, then $L$ will meet $C$ at $P$ and will have the same direction.  That's all.  There is nothing in general to say whether or not $L$ will also meet $C$ at some other point, and as your example shows, this may well happen with a cubic.

It won't happen with a quadratic since a quadratic always "curves in the same direction", therefore moving away from the tangent.  But it can also happen with a sine curve, for example - draw some pictures and you will easily find a tangent which intersects the curve again at one other point, or two, or in fact many - and it can happen with various other curves too.

In fact, a line will always meet a cubic curve in exactly three points (if you allow complex solutions: at most three, if not).  In saying this, you have to count a tangent as two meeting points, and the third will usually be somewhere else.  In the case where $C$ is $y=x^3$ and $P$ is the origin, the tangent $L$ is $y=0$.  Here $P$ is also a point of inflection and all three meeting points are the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David. That helped alot. But why do people refer to tangent line as "a line that touches a curve once at a specific point?"

Comment: the purpose of a tangent line is not so much that it (locally) touches the curve at one point, instead it's the best linear approximation to the function of the curve at that point. Eg sps you're driving in a car and want to know the total elapsed distance. A guess would be look at the speedometer at some time and multiply by the total time. Of course this is incorrect as the speed changes a lot. Instead the speed is good for short periods of time (eg 1s), and this local linear approx is the derivative. Adding together distances calculated from 1s intervals gives the total distance (integral).

Comment: @TobyHarnish Re: "why do people refer to tangent line as a line that touches a curve once at a specific point?" - I don't really know :)  This is clearly wrong, as is shown by your cubic example.  Just a guess - maybe it is because they are visualising the case of a circle, where indeed the tangent never touches the curve again.

Comment: The last paragraph seems to be missing the word "cubic"

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I first thought this last paragraph is just wrong but your explanation is much better. Edited in the word cubic, now it is correct.

Comment: @TobyHarnish,David: The reason is probably that... long long ago geometers were interested in only circles and at most conic sections, for which a line is tangent iff it touches at exactly one point... (Let's ignore the parabola, okay?) [Um, in case it wasn't clear, I was joking.]

Comment: @TobyHarnish re "why do people refer to tangent line as a line that touches a curve once at a specific point?"—the first time I heard the word *tangent* was in my high school geometry class, to describe a line that intersects a *circle* in exactly one point. And for circles, the two conditions are equivalent.

Comment: @quarague I did mean cubic, thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 6):

### VISUALIZATION :

Here is a Degree 4 Polynomial :
[image: DEGREE 4]

**There are atleast 3 types of tangents here.**

Type 1 : We can see that the lower thin Purple line is tangent & touches only once.

**That is not the only type of tangent which might occur.**

Type 2 : The thick Purple Solid line is a tangent at around $(1.9,-25)$ & amazingly , that tangent line touches the curve again tangentially at around $(-1.9,-2)$ !
Hence tangents can touch the curve multiple times.

Type 3 : The thick Purple Dotted line is a tangent at around $(-0.1,-1)$ & it intersects the curve at around $(-2.9,22)$ & around $(-2.4,-20)$

**Over-all : A tangent may touch exactly once or a tangent might be tangential multiple times or a tangent might intersect the curve multiples times.**

Here is a Degree 6 curve , where we might want to identify such types of tangents :
[image: DEGREE 6]

It has a tangent line which is tangential at 2 Points & that tangent line intersects the curve at 2 other Points !

**[[ IMAGES GENERATED COURTESY OF WOLFRAM ONLINE TOOL AND THEN MODIFIED ]]**

### ADDENDUM :

**(A)** Why is it claimed that a tangent touches only once ?
**(1)** It is a wrong claim , based on faulty thinking.
**(2)** It occurs because the Derivation of the tangent line uses a technique which might misleading into that thinking.
Basically , that technique uses a line drawn to intersect a curve at 2 Points. then the two Points are moved closer (by changing the Parameters) & then the tangent line is claimed to be the limit when the 2 Points coincide to become a Single Point. That is true , though it makes some faulty thinking that the tangent will not touch or intersect later. It only makes the local intersection a tangent when the 2 Points coincide & merge to a Single Point.

**(B)** Degree of Polynomial is almost immaterial , such tangents might occur for Degree 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ....

**(C)** Though it is not universal , there are certain classes of curves where tangent line will touch exactly once : Eg , Circle , Ellipse , Parabola

**(D)** In 3D Case , we have the concept of tangent plane , where tangency & intersection can occur like the 2D Case tangent line.